# ExtJS Tab Panel - Tabs Not Displaying

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

I am trying to setup a tab panel on my page, which contains 2 tabs with both containing grids. However, I cannot get my first grid panel to even display as a tab.

```
var tabHistoryPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',
{
    name: 'historyTabs',
    id: 'historyTabs',
    border: false,
    flex: 1,
    activeTab: 0, 
//  layout: 'fit', 
//  style: 'border-top: 1px solid #4c535c;',    
    items: [                    
        actionsGrid,
        {
            title: 'Test',
            border: false,
            html: 'Testing'
        }
    ],
    dockedItems:
    [ .............
```

And here is the grid panel I am trying to add in. 
I can get the 'Test' tab to display, but not the actionsGrid. Am I missing something here?

```
var actionsGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',
    {
        title: 'Property',
        id: 'userActionsGrid',          
    //  style: 'border-top: 1px solid #4c535c;',
        border: false,
        flex: 1,
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
        {................
```

My tabHistoryPanel is contained in this layout. Essentially, there is a tree structure above the panel with the tabs.

```
return Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',
    {
        border: false,
        layout:
        {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items:
            [
                userTree,
                tabHistoryPanel
            ]
    });
```

Comment: How are the tabs contained, in what kind of layout?

Comment: The layout setting of tabHistoryPanel or the layout of which tabHistoryPanel is contained?

Comment: `tabHistoryPanel` is a tab panel, so it's a card layout. What is the layout hierarchy *above* the tab panel.

Comment: I believe I added the code in for what you are referring to. I'm not sure why that would be an issue, as I do have a tab appearing that I can click and view, in which I can see the HTML get displayed. My grid also is 100% functional when it stands on its own.

Comment: Are you getting any debugger messages?

Comment: No, I am getting no complaints. Really confused on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this. Instead of assigning tab panel to a variable and putting it in my returned panel, I had to define it explicitly in the returned panel. See below. Couldn't tell you why it didn't work before, but its fixed.

```
return Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',
    {
        border: false,
        layout:
        {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items:
        [
            userTree,
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                name: 'historyTabs',
                id: 'historyTabs',
                flex: 1,
                activeTab: 0, 
                dockedItems: historyToolbar,    
                items: [                                                            
                        actionsGrid,
                        {
                            title: 'Test',
                            border: false,
                            html: 'Testing'
                        }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```